# How to supress 'star imports' warnings from Spyder IDE?

Tags: python, ide, spyder

While working on Spyder and importing some libraries as:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
```

I get this waning message at every line containing functions from those libraries:

```
somefunction may be undefined or defined from star imports
```

The warnings are harmless but it is quite annoying to see all my code underlined in yellow. Is there any way to supress specifically those warnings?

Comment: Don’t do wildcard imports. Do `from OpenGL import GL`, then all the calls become `GL.xxx`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this seems to work for me

```
from OpenGL.GL import * # analysis:ignore
```

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to work for the one line only, and I'm guessing is supress all other warnings as well.

Comment: correct (i guess). Better not to use import *, you could do something like  import OpenGL.GL as ogl and prefix all imported functions with ogl. Then you dont have bogus warnings to deal with