# pyspark how to return the average of a column based on the value of another column?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I wouldn't expect this to be difficult, but I'm having trouble understanding how to take the average of a column in my spark dataframe.

The dataframe looks like:

```
+-------+------------+--------+------------------+
|Private|Applications|Accepted|              Rate|
+-------+------------+--------+------------------+
|    Yes|         417|     349|0.8369304556354916|
|    Yes|        1899|    1720|0.9057398630858347|
|    Yes|        1732|    1425|0.8227482678983834|
|    Yes|         494|     313|0.6336032388663968|
|     No|        3540|    2001|0.5652542372881356|
|     No|        7313|    4664|0.6377683577191303|
|    Yes|         619|     516|0.8336025848142165|
|    Yes|         662|     513|0.7749244712990937|
|    Yes|         761|     725|0.9526938239159002|
|    Yes|        1690|    1366| 0.808284023668639|
|    Yes|        6075|    5349|0.8804938271604938|
|    Yes|         632|     494|0.7816455696202531|
|     No|        1208|     877|0.7259933774834437|
|    Yes|       20192|   13007|0.6441660063391442|
|    Yes|        1436|    1228|0.8551532033426184|
|    Yes|         392|     351|0.8954081632653061|
|    Yes|       12586|    3239|0.2573494358811378|
|    Yes|        1011|     604|0.5974282888229476|
|    Yes|         848|     587|0.6922169811320755|
|    Yes|        8728|    5201|0.5958982584784601|
+-------+------------+--------+------------------+
```

I want to return the average of the `Rate` column when `Private` is equal to "Yes".  How can I do this?

Comment: Filter and then calculate the average ?

Comment: exactly, I am not sure how to calculate the average.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df.filter(df['Private'] == 'Yes').agg({'Rate': 'avg'}).collect()[0]
```

Comment: I'm not sure filter works this way. Filter works on the index and column headers.

Comment: I have tried `privateRate = df.filter(df['Private'] == 'Yes').agg({'Rate': 'avg'})`,
but `print(privateRate)` returns `DataFrame[avg(Rate): double]`.  Seems like its close, but I need to see the actual number @Vishnudev

Comment: spyder is warning me "undefined name *display*"

Answer (score 1):

A third version to do the same would be:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, avg
df_avg = df.filter(df["Private"] == "Yes").agg(avg(col("Rate")))
df_avg.show()
```

Comment: I think this, along with Vishnudev 's answer are working, but the answer isn't displaying properly.  Like I mentioned before, printing this gives me:`DataFrame[avg(Rate): double]` and I need to see the number.  I'm curious about the display function you mentioned, it seems like I need to import something first for that to work.

Comment: df_avg.show() gives me a very long error (one I have been seeing a lot when trying very different things)

Answer (score 1):

This would work in scala. pyspark code should be very similar.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = List(
("yes", 10),
("yes", 30),
("No", 40)).toDF("private", "rate")

val df = l.toDF(List("private", "rate"))

val window =Window.partitionBy($"private")

df.
    withColumn("avg", 
                when($"private" === "No", null).
                otherwise(avg($"rate").over(window))
            ).
    show()
```

**Input DF**

```
+-------+----+
|private|rate|
+-------+----+
|    yes|  10|
|    yes|  30|
|     No|  40|
+-------+----+
```

**output df**

```
+-------+----+----+
|private|rate| avg|
+-------+----+----+
|     No|  40|null|
|    yes|  10|20.0|
|    yes|  30|20.0|
+-------+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, mean, lit

df.where(col("Private")==lit("Yes")).select(mean(col("Rate"))).collect()
```

Comment: spyder gives me a code analysis warning, "'lit' may be undefined or defined from star imports".  This also causes an error while running the code

Comment: Ou, try now - ```F.lit(...)``` should do

Comment: I'm receiving a big long error.  I've seen it several times on this project but it doesn't always come up.  I'm beginning to wonder if the problem isn't this part of my code but something else? Which would be odd because I can run up to these lines without issue.

Comment: Maybe it's this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46799137/how-to-supress-star-imports-warnings-from-spyder-ide

Comment: Out of curiosity- try it now (without star import)

Comment: I don't have the same warning from spyder, but I still get the tremendously long error

Comment: I'm starting to thing - ```from pyspark.sql import functions as F``` is the problem here (which shouldn't be the case in general). You can check now - but if it's still not it, that some environmental discrepancy, which I just cannot reproduce...

Comment: if I remove the `.collect()` and print there is no error, but I am back to the `DataFrame[avg(Rate): double]` output

Comment: Because you haven't evaluated it. I.e. until ```.collect()``` nothing material really happened- your query is executed just once you call (```.collect()```, or ```.show()``` for instance)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207505/discussion-between-jacob-myer-and-grzegorz-skibinski).