# pyspark: when printing my dataframe, why don't I see the actual values? I just get DataFrame[avg(Rate): double]

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to return the average of a column.  When I go to print the result, I can't see an actual value.

My dataframe (before the following code):

```
+-------+------------+--------+------------------+
|Private|Applications|Accepted|              Rate|
+-------+------------+--------+------------------+
|    Yes|         417|     349|0.8369304556354916|
|    Yes|        1899|    1720|0.9057398630858347|
|    Yes|        1732|    1425|0.8227482678983834|
|    Yes|         494|     313|0.6336032388663968|
|     No|        3540|    2001|0.5652542372881356|
|     No|        7313|    4664|0.6377683577191303|
|    Yes|         619|     516|0.8336025848142165|
|    Yes|         662|     513|0.7749244712990937|
|    Yes|         761|     725|0.9526938239159002|
|    Yes|        1690|    1366| 0.808284023668639|
|    Yes|        6075|    5349|0.8804938271604938|
|    Yes|         632|     494|0.7816455696202531|
|     No|        1208|     877|0.7259933774834437|
|    Yes|       20192|   13007|0.6441660063391442|
|    Yes|        1436|    1228|0.8551532033426184|
|    Yes|         392|     351|0.8954081632653061|
|    Yes|       12586|    3239|0.2573494358811378|
|    Yes|        1011|     604|0.5974282888229476|
|    Yes|         848|     587|0.6922169811320755|
|    Yes|        8728|    5201|0.5958982584784601|
+-------+------------+--------+------------------+
```

This is my code:

```
privateRate = df.filter(df["Private"] == "Yes").agg(avg(col("Rate")))

print(privateRate)

#returns:
DataFrame[avg(Rate): double]
```

I have also tried:

```
privateRate.show()

#returns a big long error
```

That error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jacob/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learning 2/M5/M5IndividualPt1.py", line 40, in <module>
    privateRate.show()
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 380, in show
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o110.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 6, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 377, in main
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 372, in process
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 393, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/jacob/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learning 2/M5/M5IndividualPt1.py", line 17, in parseLine
    apps = int(fields[2])
IndexError: list index out of range


        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:592)

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:575)

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)

        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)

        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)

        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)

        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)

        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)

        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)

        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)

        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)

        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)

        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Driver stacktrace:

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)

        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)

        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)

        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)

        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)

        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)

        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)

        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)

        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)

        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)

        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)

        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)

        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 377, in main
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 372, in process
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 393, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/jacob/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learning 2/M5/M5IndividualPt1.py", line 17, in parseLine
    apps = int(fields[2])
IndexError: list index out of range


        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:592)

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:575)

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)

        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)

        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)

        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)

        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)

        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)

        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)

        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)

        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)

        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)

        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

1 more


20/02/09 14:25:10 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
20/02/09 14:25:21 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 6)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 377, in main
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 372, in process
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 393, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/jacob/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learning 2/M5/M5IndividualPt1.py", line 17, in parseLine
    apps = int(fields[2])
IndexError: list index out of range

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:592)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:575)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
20/02/09 14:25:22 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
```

I have seen that long error come up a few times and I wonder if it is somewhat unrelated to my code but more my individual environment?

Comment: you have already asked the question here, if answer is not working put that as part of the comment rather than opening a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60139613/pyspark-how-to-return-the-average-of-a-column-based-on-the-value-of-another-colu

Answer (score 2):

Spark uses the concept of lazy evaluation. Meaning, Spark will wait until the very last moment to execute the graph of computation instructions. So, when you run this statement

```
privateRate = df.filter(df["Private"] == "Yes").agg(avg(col("Rate")))
```

All what Spark is doing is simply building a plan to execute your transformations but never actually execute it. That's why you don't see the error yet if your data has an issue. The gotcha happens when you call `.show()` on it. It is then when you take things from being on the logical transformation level to the Action level. An action instructs Spark to compute the results from the series of transformations that you performed above. Now, looking at your error message, it seems like your actual error is here:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Unfortunately, it is hard to tell what caused this error without seeing your whole code and understand the structure of your tables. But hopefully this answer can help you narrow down your focus on what you should be chasing.

Comment: That really helps me understand, thank you.  Unfortunately I don't know where to go from here to diagnose the issue.  I can share my whole code in the messenger... although I am not sure how to initiate that.