# How to disable warnings and errors due to star import when developing a package (I am using Spyder)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

My package structure looks like this

```
mypackage
│   LICENSE
│   pyproject.toml
│   README.md
│   requiremets.txt            
├───docs
├───scripts          
├───src
│   └───mypackage
│          config.py
│          first_module.py
│          second_module.py
│          __init__.py         
└───tests
```

the content of my `__init__.p`y is this

```
from .first_module import *  # NOQA
from .second_module import *  # NOQA
```

and in `second_module.py` I have the following

```
from .first_module import *  # NOQA analysis:ignore
```

I run `pip install -e .` to have my package in the right place while developing.

My `second_module.py` is full of these warnings

```
'myfunction' may be undefined, or defined in star imports .first_module (pyflakes E)
```

and these errors

```
'MY_CONST' is not defined (mypy)
```

How to disable such warnings/errors?
If it may be useful, I am using the following IDE

```
* Spyder version: 5.2.2 None
* Python version: 3.9.12 64-bit
* Qt version: 5.9.7
* PyQt5 version: 5.9.2
* Operating System: Windows 10
```

I have found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46799137/how-to-supress-star-imports-warnings-from-spyder-ide) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753804/import-a-secondary-file-in-spyder-ide-with-star-import-with-no-warnings) and I am aware that star imports shall be avoided, but I also read that when developing a package with the described structure (which is one of the recommended btw), then using star imports in such a specific manner is the way to go.

**EDIT**: I found a way for circumnavigating it and it is to add a `# noqa` at the end of each line where I get the warning. But that happens on a tons of lines and it is very annoying to fix the code in this way.

**EDIT 2**: I have tried to create a `~/.flake8` file with the following content

```
[flake8]
extend-ignore = F403,F405
```

But it didn't work. I also tried replacing `extend-ignore` with `ignore` but I got the same result.

**EDIT 3**:
I observed that by having the aforementioned `.flake8` file in my project root folder and by running `flake8.exe ./src/mypackage/first_module.py`, then `F405` is correctly ignored, but running `pyflakes.exe ./src/mypackage/first_module.py` the `F405` warning is still there.
Hence, once shall tell `pyflakes` to add `extend-ignore = F403,F405` to its `flake8` config file, but is not possible since `pyflakes` does not use any config file..

Comment: As the warning says, it comes from`pyflakes`. I suggest you google "python pyflakes" to find the documentation about how to configure it.

Comment: I got it. And the answer is that `pyflakes` cannot be configured. So there appear to be no solution to my problem as-is in Spyder. I raised an issue in their issue tracker.  Nevertheless, I could use `flake8` externally.

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you want to import your first module to second then use

`from .first_module import *` instead of `from .first_module *`

also in your terminal invoke python and then check whether you have pyflakes installed if not then install it using below command

**pip install pyflakes**

Hope it helps as per the error shared by you.

Comment: Actually I mistakenly copied/pasted. Edited. 
I have pyflakes installed (otherwise I would not get any error).

Comment: Then i would recommend you better go with the best approach of importing the modules or libraries you require to be used.
You can also check Flake8 rules in below 

[link](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/F405.html)